# Trying to detect undefined in hta - typeof returns object

Tags: javascript, hta

I'm trying to skip doing an action when a value is undefined.

When I run the following code it alerts, for example, "row 114 has undefined object users". This is an hta file on a machine running IE9. I have tried various ways of checking for undefined but not sure what I am doing wrong.Checking for currentcell != null does not work.

```
 var currentcell;
    for(var i = new_promotion_startrow; i<new_employees_endrow;i++)
    {
    currentcell = sheet.Cells(i,21);
    if(currentcell != 'undefined' && currentcell != 'None')
    {
    alert('row ' + i + ' has ' + currentcell + ' ' + typeof(currentCell) + ' users.');
    }
    }
```

Comment: What type of object is `sheet`? If you are trying to test the return value from a COM object, that might be relevant because the object might be returning `Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [strict comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators):

```
if (currentcell !== undefined && currentcell !== null) {...}
```